# Brand name simplifier

Tags: string, algorithm, generator

Is there an established algorithm/library to create shorter, simpler strings based on words? I need to simplify a lot of brand name to generate our own part no, that we use in the warehouse.

Examples:

```
AECW....A E C WHITLOCK
BATI....BENATI
BDER....BOMBARDIER
PACC....PACCAR PARTS DIV
JAGR....JAEGER
JCB.....JCB
JNDR....JOHN DEERE
```

So, is there a way to generate them or my only option is to create a database table which contains all of them?

Another reason why I want them generated: I already have (and need) a table where all of the brand names are stored and I don't want to store the simplified ones If it is not necessary. Also, I would still need something that generates them for the first time.

Edit: Okay, I need to store  them, but generating an abbreviation is still a question.

Comment: Even if you generate the abbreviations, how would you avoid collisions without storing them?

Comment: Do you want to generate those specifically, or any shortenings?

Comment: Depending on the use collisions aren't always a problem. For instant displaying a abbreviated product name in a certain product category.

Comment: I still need the generator, but you're right, I can't avoid storing them.

Comment: With this examples I dont think you can find any example, I think it is depends more on people how use this brands to simplify their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate abbreviations just remove vowels (PL/SQL code as example):

```sql
create function abbr(s varchar2) return varchar2 as
  r varchar2(4000) := upper(s);
begin
  for i in 5..regexp_count(r, '[A-Z]') loop
    r := regexp_replace(r, '([A-Z])[AEIOU]', '\1', 1, 1);
  end loop;
  return substr(regexp_replace(r, '[^A-Z]'), 1, 4);
end;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bed1b/1)

```
A E C WHITLOCK    AECW
BENATI            BNTI
BOMBARDIER        BMBR
PACCAR PARTS DIV  PCCR
JAEGER            JGER
JCB               JCB
JOHN DEERE        JHND
```

Comment: An okay solution, I just need something to modify one If there is a collision.